# How to get nodes from relationships with any depth including relation filter

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using a query similar to this one:

```
(n)-[*]->(m)
Any depth.
```

But I cannot filter the relation name in such a query like this:

```
(n)-[*:DOES]->(m)
Any depth.
```

I need to filter the relation name since there are different relations on the related path. If it helps, here is my graph:

```
CREATE (Computer { name:'Computer' }),(Programming { name:'Programming' }),(Java { name:'Java' }),(GUI { name:'GUI' }),(Button { name:'Button' }), Computer<-[:IS]-Programming, Programming<-[:IS]-Java, Java<-[:IS]-GUI, GUI<-[:IS]-Button, (Ekin { name:'Ekin' }), (Gunes { name:'Gunes' }), (Ilker {name:'Ilker'}), Ekin-[:DOES]->Programming, Ilker-[:DOES]->Java, Ilker-[:DOES]->Button, Gunes-[:DOES]->Java
```

I'd like to get the names (Ekin, Ilker and Gunes) which have "DOES" relationship connected to "Programming" with any depth.

**Edit:**

I'm able to get the values I want by merging two different queries' results (think 13 is the top node that I want to reach):

```
START n=node(13) 
MATCH p-[:DOES]->()-[*]->(n) 
RETURN DISTINCT p

START n=node(13) 
MATCH p-[:DOES]->(n) 
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

I want to do it in a single query.

Comment: Try moving the asterisk to the other side of the relationship type, like so: `(n)-[:DOES*]->(m)`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: It returns the values what (n)-[:DOES]->(m) returns. No change.

Comment: Yes there is change, your match pattern now states both variable length and relationship type. If you get the same data back that's because there are no relationships of that type and direction longer than one in your graph. Make a path of your pattern and drop the directionality and you'll see the difference, i.e. compare `MATCH p=(n)-[:DOES*]-(m) RETURN p` with `MATCH p=(n)-[:DOES]-(m) RETURN p`.

Comment: I answered your question about filtering variable length relationships on type, but not your question about how to get the specific data you want. The answer is that none of "Ekin, Iker and Gunes" are connected to "Programming" by multiple relationships of type "DOES", so you need to take the "IS" relationship into account as well. It's hard to answer unless you are more explicit about your model, but possibly what you want is something like `MATCH (p)<-[:IS*0..]-()<-[:DOES]-(n) RETURN DISTINCT n`. That's based on my guess of what "IS" means in your graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the matching pattern to "p-[:DOES]->()-[*0..]->n",

```
Match p-[:DOES]->()-[*0..]->n
Return distinct p.name
```

The variable length relationship "[*]" means 1..*. You need 0..* length relationships on the path.

Answer (score 2):

Just to update the answer with Neo4j 3.0.

```
MATCH p-[:DOES*0..]->(n)
RETURN DISTINCT(p.name)
```

It returns the same result as the accepted answer.